# How to infer the possible values for the final two coordinates of a trapezoid when all 4 line lengths are known

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I have a trapezoid where I know the length of all 4 lines, and I know the coordinates of two of the corners. How do I find the coordinates of the remaining two corners in JavaScript?

NOTE: All 4 lines are of different length, ie this is not an isosceles trapezoid

Here's a little diagram in case it helps:

```
       L3  
    D ____ C
     /    \
 L4 /      \ L2 
    --------
  A    L1    B
```

I know the coordinates of A and B, and the length of L1, L2, L3, and L4 (Which are all different). I just need to get all of the possible sets of coordinates for D and C!

Comment: The trapezoid is not uniquely defined - there are two possibilities

Comment: I understand that! I was hoping to find all possible sets of coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop vertical lines from points C and D to the line AB to find their projections on E and F on AB:

[image]

Now AED and BFC are right triangles with the same height. Let's call the height `h`. From Pythagoras:

```
a² + h² = L4²     and     b² + h² = L2²
```

Subtracting one equation from the other you get: `a² - b² = L4² - L2²`

Also you can divide L1 into segments AE, EF, and FB, so the length of L1 must be:

```
L1 = a + L3 + b    =>    a + b = L1 - L3
```

Therefore we have a system of equations in a and b:

```
a² - b² = L4² - L2²
a + b  = L3 - L1
```

Using the fact that `a² - b² = (a+b)(a-b)` and the above equation, you get:

```
(L3 - L1)(a - b) = L4² - L2²   =>   a - b = (L4² - L2²)/(L3 - L1)
```

(Note that L1 and L3 can not be equal. If L1 = L3, there is an infinite number of solutions.)

So the equations simplify to:

```
a + b  = L3 - L1
a - b = (L4² - L2²)/(L3 - L1)
```

The solution is:

```
a = (L3 - L1 + (L4² - L2²)/(L3 - L1)) / 2
b = (L3 - L1 - (L4² - L2²)/(L3 - L1)) / 2
```

The height of the trapezoid is:

```
h = sqrt(L4² - a²) = sqrt(L2² - b²)
```

You could now use `a` to solve for the angle at point A and `b` to solve the angle at point B, and use them to calculate the coordinates for C and D. Or you can use `a`, `b`, and `h` directly.

For example: suppose A is at the origin (0,0) and B is at (L1, 0). Then the two solutions are:

- C is at `(a, h)` and D is at `(L1 - b, h)`
- C is at `(a, -h)` and D is at `(L1 - b, -h)`

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!!! How would this change if the trapezoid was sideways, ie if the axes were reversed?

Comment: That's just a matter of changing switching the X and Y coordinates, for example C would be at (sqrt(L4² - a²), a)

Comment: I think I may be having order of operations issues in JS: `const square = (num) => Math.pow(num, 2);
 const sidesDiffSqrd = square(L4) - square(L2);
 const baseDiffs = L3 - L1;
 const diffsRatio = sidesDiffSqrd / baseDiffs;
 const a = (baseDiffs + diffsRatio) / 2;
 const b = (baseDiffs - diffsRatio) / 2;`

Comment: Gives me: `{ a: -4.25, b: 2.25  }` but the offsets should not be negative, right?

Comment: This is with `{
 A: { x: 0, y: 0 },
 B: { x: 10, y: 0 },
 L1: 10,
 L2: 6,
 L3: 8,
 L4: 7,
}`

Comment: Yes one negative value means the trapezoid is skewed to one side. Two negative values is possible if L3 > L1